# Middleware School Tutorial on Consuming SOAP WSDL-First Service using Anypoint Studio Web Service Cosumer

Tags: web-services, mule

Middleware School has this beautiful tutorial on [Consuming SOAP WSDL-First Service](http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/consuming-wsdl-first-service/) using Mule.

This tutorial uses SOAP CXF Component. It works for me. My question is how should I substitute SOAP CXF component with the new Web Service Consumer Connector (available in Anypoint Studio) and still get the tutorial working?

```
<ws:consumer-config name="WebService_IP2GeoSoap" wsdlLocation="http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?wsdl" service="IP2Geo" port="IP2GeoSoap" serviceAddress="http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
```

...

```
    <sub-flow name="resolveIPFlowNew" doc:name="resolveIPFlowNew">
    <set-payload value="#[{'118.200.217.38', ''}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="WebService_IP2GeoSoap" operation="ResolveIP" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="resolveIPFlowOld" doc:name="resolveIPFlowOld">
    <set-payload value="#[{'118.200.217.38', ''}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ResolveIP" clientClass="training.soap.ip2geo.IP2Geo" port="IP2GeoSoap" doc:name="CXF"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</sub-flow>

<flow name="soapclientFlow2" doc:name="soapclientFlow2">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="soapclient/wsdlfirst" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="resolveIPFlowNew" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
</flow>
```

Referring to this, using Anypoint Studio it works for me running resolveIPFlowOld but it doesn't work for me using resolveIPFlowNew. The error

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
WARN  2014-05-29 14:12:12,698 [[traininggovau].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=[Ljava.lang.Object;, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.OutputPayloadInterceptor.handleMessage(OutputPayloadInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:462)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:236)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.process(WSConsumer.java:150)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:206)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:511)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.routeEvent(AbstractTransportMessageProcessTemplate.java:80)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:76)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1$1.process(FlowProcessingPhase.java:63)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.FlowProcessingPhase$1.run(FlowProcessingPhase.java:62)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=[Ljava.lang.Object;, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:250)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:358)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:313)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.support.OutputPayloadInterceptor.handleMessage(OutputPayloadInterceptor.java:91)
    ... 127 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just got it working using this

```
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?wsdl" service="IP2Geo" port="IP2GeoSoap" serviceAddress="http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
<data-mapper:config name="JSON_To_Xml_ResolveIP_" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml_resolveip_.grf" doc:name="JSON_To_Xml_ResolveIP_"/>
<data-mapper:config name="JSON_To_Xml_ResolveIP__1" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml_resolveip__1.grf" doc:name="JSON_To_Xml_ResolveIP__1"/>
<data-mapper:config name="Xml_ResolveIPResponse__To_JSON" transformationGraphPath="xml_resolveipresponse__to_json.grf" doc:name="Xml_ResolveIPResponse__To_JSON"/>
<sub-flow name="resolveIPFlowOld" doc:name="resolveIPFlowOld">
    <set-payload value="#[{'118.200.217.38', ''}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ResolveIP" clientClass="training.soap.ip2geo.IP2Geo" port="IP2GeoSoap" doc:name="CXF"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
</sub-flow>
<sub-flow name="resolveIPFlowNew" doc:name="resolveIPFlowNew">
    <set-payload value="{&quot;ipAddress&quot; : &quot;118.200.217.38&quot;, &quot;licenseKey&quot; : null}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="JSON_To_Xml_ResolveIP__1" doc:name="JSON To Xml&lt;ResolveIP&gt;"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="ResolveIP" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_ResolveIPResponse__To_JSON" doc:name="Xml&lt;ResolveIPResponse&gt; To JSON"/>
</sub-flow>
<flow name="soapclientFlow" doc:name="soapclientFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="resolveIPFlowNew" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
```

[image]